# Change the default order of retrieval in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loopbackjs

I have a loopback api that retrieves some objects. These objects has a property `createdAt`. I want to change the order of the objects that are retrieved by the api based on this property. What is the best way to achieve this??

Comment: you want to manually reorder. simply create new object and assign values using old object.

Comment: try converting object to array than sort it as object cant be sorted in JavaScript

Comment: of course, I can order the objects after retrieving but I want the ordering to be performed by the loopback api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the order filter in several ways, on your :

**REST API :**

This is for one property and you can choose ASC or DESC :

```
filter[order]=createdAt <ASC|DESC>
```

This is for more than one property :

```
filter[order][0]=createdAt <ASC|DESC>&filter[order][1][updatedAt]=<ASC|DESC>...
```

**NODE API**

```
model.find({
  order: 'createdAt DESC',
});
```

[HERE the official documentation of the explanation above.](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Order-filter.html)

**MODEL DEFINITION JSON**

You can use the scope property in your JSON model file and I recommend it.

```
"scope": {
    "order": "createdAt ASC",
    "where": {
      "field": "something" // you can use the where filter also ...
    }
  },
```

[Check this official documentation for more information about SCOPES](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Model-definition-JSON-file.html)

Comment: Is it possible to disable the default sorting/ordering?

Comment: @sttaq https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/437 disableDefaultSort may do the thing also check https://loopback.io/pages/en/lb3/readmes/loopback-connector-mongodb.html

Comment: thanks, looks like it will apply to the data source not a particular entity?

Comment: @sttaq yes applied to datasource